# How Can I Skip Skill Animations?

Tags: rainbow-moon

I noticed that I can skip the animation for Baldren's `Shield Bash` skill, but for others I can't.  Is there an option somewhere or does something else allow me to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[If the skill occurs on the field, you can't skip the animation until you've beaten the game. If the skill occurs over a separate background, you can skip it after you've executed it a certain number of times by pressing R2.](http://www.eastasiasoft.com/index.php/forum/11-rainbow-moon/2567-battle-animationsspells?limit=6&start=12#2663)

> The game is distinguishing between so called "black screen skills" that are mostly longer and have a black background and "on field skills" that take place directly on the battle field.
>
> For black screen skills, there is a hidden counter for each one and once you have used the skill a certain number of times, the skip option will simply unlock for this skill.
>
> In general the skip counter is higher for the first skills you can obtain and will decrease more and more for the longer and more advanced skills.
>
> On field skills can never be skipped during the normal game, however they can, once you reach the end game content.
>
> If skipping is possible, a new option will appear in the on-screen dialog that is visible during pattern selection.

Comment: Thank you for this.  The longer (fancy background) skills were irritating the heck out of me.  I can only watch Hydra Byte and Flamy Gorge so many times....  D: